# Finding the branch location of a file when multiple branches via Eclipse and Windows 10

Tags: windows, file, branch

I am using Eclipse with Java and git.  We had been using gitscm and we never made branches in addition to master.  We would make changes to master, push to gerrit, get reviewed and it would merge into master.

We have recently switched to github, and we need to make a private branch from master, commit, do a pull request and have it merged.

Since this is a Java project I created most of the classes right from Eclipse; however, occasionally there would be an xml file we needed, so I copied the mxl file into the correct location in the workspace and did a refresh from Eclipse.

My question is, now when we have a second branch how do we know the correct location?  I don't see anything different.  Here is an example.  I currently have just master.  I made a "tonytest" project.  The workspace is c:\github_workspaces\tonytest and the filed in it are .settings, src, target, .classpath, .project and pom.xml as you would expect.  Under src/main/java/tonytest I made a TonyMainTest.java class:

```
package tonytest;

public class TonyMainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is from master");
}
```

}

through eclipse, and I find the file in the directory.  Running it gives me "This is from master".

Now I switch to a new branch that I create, testbranch.  In the tonytest workspace there is no new directory indicating a branch. I change the class to print "This is from branch" which it does. I open the file and it says "this is from branch" on the class.  But what happened to the "This is from master" file?  It should still be around because the master branch still exists.  And switching back to master, the class still says "This is from branch".

I guess actually this does not really have anything to do with which version of git is being used.